# Are there any custom implementations of Roslyn Analyzers for detecting internationalization issues?

Tags: github, internationalization, roslyn-code-analysis, static-code-analysis

Currently Roslyn Analyzers provide static code analysis for some Globalization issues as provided here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/globalization-warnings?view=vs-2019

These rulesets are not enough as they leave out some common internationalization(i18n) checks like

1. Hardcoded strings
2. Concatenation
3. String expansion
4. Static file references etc .......

Since Roslyn Analyzers are open source, somebody might have already implemented their own custom analyzers for i18n. How do I know if such implementations are already present on github ? I tried google search for this but couldn't find any useful information. On Github, the src for roslyn-analyzers has been forked more than 200 times but there is no easy way to search for this information in the forks.